# ¿Cómo se escribe "x y y" ó "x e y"?, ¿“α o ω” ó “α u ω”?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario-técnico

Escribiendo textos con fórmulas matemáticas a menudo te encuentras con este tipo de problemas con los símbolos matemáticos. Pongo unos cuantos ejemplos:

1. "... donde *x* **e** *y* son variables reales ..."
2. "... donde el valor es *α* **u** *ω*", en este caso si ponemos los nombre de las letras en vez creo que no hay duda: "donde el valor es alfa u omega."
3. "... donde *a* es un entero **e** *i* es la constante imaginaria."
4. Cuando **y** predece a un símbolo cuyo nombre empieza con el sonido **i** como por ejemplo integral, pero que también podrías leer de otra forma (por ejemplo "la integral").

¿Es correcto como lo he escrito en los ejemplos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta a tu pregunta es: si, el uso es correcto en los casos 1, 2 y 3.

En el caso 4 mi elección personal sería escribir "y la [símbolo de integración]" y leer "y la integral".

La RAE describe el uso de la conjunción "e" [aquí](http://dle.rae.es/e), y el de la conjunción "u" [aquí](http://dle.rae.es/u).

La conjunción "y" se sustituye por "e" ante palabras que empiezan por "i" o "hi":

> Juan e Ignacio.
>
> Padre e hijo.

Excepción a esta regla son:

- al principio de interrogación o admiración

  > ¿Y Ignacio?
  >
  > ¡Y Isidoro también comprometido!
- ni cuando la palabra siguiente empieza por y o por la sílaba hie:

  > Ocaña y Yepes.
  >
  > Tigre y hiena.

La conjunción "o" se sustituye por "u" ante palabras que empiezan por "o" o por "ho":

> diez u once
>
> belga u holandés.

Esta sustitución de "y" por "e", y de "o" por "u" es necesaria para evitar el hiato que se produciría. Por ejemplo, el caso "padre y hijo" sería muy difícil de pronunciar sin interrupción.

En los países que pronuncian la letra "y" como "ye" y no como "i griega" sería posible escribir "**x** y **y**" y pronunciar "**x** y **ye**".

Comment: por lo menos en Cuba nosotros escribimos "**x** y **y**" y pronunciamos "**x** y **ye**." aunque cuando en el caso de que no está precedida por una **y** le decimos **i griega** es más bien elección del que habla

Comment: Además con la nueva ortografía, el único nombre de la letra _y_ es _ye_ (aunque se tiene que mencionar que tampoco se ha censurado el uso de _i_ _griega_)

Comment: @guifa Creo que lo que dices no es correcto. La edición 23ra del diccionario de la RAE (que aún está en preparación) lista los dos nombres. Véase [aquí](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=lWblLoILF2x5veXwHXi).

Comment: Yo me refiero a la Ortografía de 2010, no a la 23ª edición del DRAE.  Puédese consultar [las novedades](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Principales_novedades_de_la_Ortografia_de_la_lengua_espanola.pdf) en el sitio de la RAE.

Comment: @guifa ¡Gracias por el enlace!

Comment: @Nico De nada.  La realidad es que aunque para mí esté bien que tengan unos nombres fijos, no me ha dado ninguna gracia la exclusión de la _ch_ y la _ll_ del abecedario.  Lo bueno es que parece que, para la formación de siglas y parecido, se seguirán admitiendo los dígrafos a pesar de que ya no se refieren a los dígrafos como letras.